# R Shiny input range slider issues

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having issues with the slider range displaying information it is not supposed to. This is what it looks like:
[range slider issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ2SA.jpg)

The numbers before the first comma are what I want displayed. My other range sliders are displaying just fine using the exact same code.

```
column(width=5,sliderInput("Macd", label = h4("MACD Delta"), min = min_delta, 
max = max_delta, value = c(min_delta, max_delta)))
```

[sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1NRw.jpg)

Comment: Hard to say without any sample of the data used to set the slider input range

Comment: @user6617454 I added an image of the data.

Comment: Pictures are usually not helping to reproduce your data. Please follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and use `dput()` on your dataframe